Numerical integration algorithm for $\int_0^{\infty} dx x^p \sin^2 x f(x)$
I would like to introduce the following kind of integrals:
$$
\int_0^{\infty} dx x^p \sin^2 x f(x),
$$
where $-3 < p < -1$, and $f(x)$ is an arbitrary `good' function which does not introduce additional poles.
I know that there a lot of specialized techniques for particular integrals. For instance Gauss–Laguerre quadrature allows one to efficiently handle the following numerical problem:
$$
\int_0^{\infty} dx \exp(-x) f(x).
$$
It is natural to expect that specialized technique is faster/accurate than generic one on average.
My questions are the following:

Is there a numerical integration algorithm which can be applied to $\int_0^{\infty} dx x^p \sin^2 x f(x)$?
Is there a generic way to build a new custom numerical integration algorithm for $\int_a^b g(x) f(x) dx$ where $g(x)$ is known in advance and $f(x)$ is user-defined?


Are you sure about the range for $p$? Assuming that $f(x)$ does not interfere in the convergence (take $f(x)=1$, for instance), you only have convergence for $-3 < p < -1$.

Thank you, @PierreCarre

More generally the Mellin transform $$\mathcal{M}_x\leftx^n \sin^2(x)\right=\int_0^{\infty} x^n, \sin^2(x), x^p , dx=2^{-n-p-2} \sin\left(\frac{\pi, (n+p)}{2}\right), \Gamma(n+p+1)$$ is only valid for $-3<\Re(n+p)<-1$.

Good note. It demonstrates that "usual approach is to force the quadrature to be exact for $f(x)=1,x,x^2,⋯,x^{2n−1}$" would be complicated...

A generic way of building a custom algorithm for $I(f)=\int_a^b f(x) g(x) dx$ (with fixed $g(x)$) is to assume that $I(f) \approx Q(f) = \sum_{i=1}^n \omega_i f(x_i)$, with $x_1, \cdots, x_n \in [a,b]$, and then compute the integration nodes $x_1, \cdots, x_n$ and the weights $\omega_1, \cdots, \omega_n$ such that the quadrature is exact for certain choices of $f$. A usual approach is to force the quadrature to be exact for $f(x) = 1, x, x^2, \cdots, x^{2n-1}$.
